# Camping in Noel Kempff Mercado National Park in Bolivia

Tags: camping, nature-and-wildlife, bolivia, national-parks

[Noel Kempff Mercado National Park](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noel_Kempff_Mercado_National_Park) is a UNESCO [World Heritage Site](http://whc.unesco.org/en/list) in the Amazon Basin, and is said to have an amazing diversity of plant and animal life. I've been looking for some information on how to visit it and how to get there (sadly, there doesn't seem to be a website in English). Unfortunatelly, [Wikitravel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Noel_Kempff_Mercado_National_Park) is useless in this case.

I'm interested in a visit that hopefully involves a few days of camping on the park's grounds. No need for actual jungle exploration, a "beaten path" route would be most sufficient. So, in relation to this, a few questions

- What would be the most convenient way to get to the park? Assume that one arrives in Bolivia by plane to a major city -- Santa Cruz or La Paz. Or perhaps there are other more convenient airports?
- Is camping allowed on the park's grounds? Are there specialized locations where one can do this? What rules apply? I'd be interested in an "official" link or reference, even if it's not in English.

If you also have taken any particular route or can recommend particular landmarks, I'd be happy to hear about this as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Footprint travel guide site has [a good page](http://www.footprinttravelguides.com/latin-america/bolivia/eastern-lowlands/hinterlands-of-santa-cruz/parque-nacional-noel-kempff-mercado/) about the park in English.

They describe how to get to the park independently and also mention a camp ground within the park at Los Fierros.

*I did not quote the relevant parts here, as I am not sure about the copyright implications.*

I think if there is a road in Bolivia, you can also park there. They are not as strict about this as other countries. Of course this is not an official answer.